# Using ng-messages with dynamic field names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I have a list of fields which are displayed using ng-repeat. The name of the input field is dynamic. How do you get ng-messages to work when using dynamic names? Below is what I've tried, but this doesn't work:

```
<form id="userForm" name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid && submit()" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="uniqueField in uniqueFields">
        <div>
            <label>{{uniqueField.form_field_label}}</label>
            <input required="{{uniqueField.isMandatory}}" name="text_{{uniqueField.form_field_id}}" ng-model="uniqueField.form_field_value" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="userForm.{{uniqueField.form_field_id}}.$error" ng-if="userForm.$submitted && uniqueField.isMandatory == true">
                <div ng-message="required">Please enter a {{uniqueField.form_field_label}}.</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You prefix the name of your input field with `text_` but you lookup `userForm.{{uniqueField.form_field_id}}.$error`. Remove the prefix and it should work :)

Here is the solution HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <form id="userForm" name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid && ctrl.submit()" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="uniqueField in ctrl.uniqueFields">
      <div>
        <label>{{uniqueField.form_field_label}}</label>
        <input required="{{uniqueField.isMandatory}}" name="{{uniqueField.form_field_id}}" ng-model="uniqueField.form_field_value" type="text">
        <div ng-messages="userForm[uniqueField.form_field_id].$error">
          <div ng-message="required">Please enter a {{uniqueField.form_field_label}}.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the Controller:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($log) {
  var ctrl = this;

  function activate() {
    ctrl.uniqueFields = [{
      form_field_label: 'Name',
      form_field_id: 'name',
      form_field_value: '',
      isMandatory: true
    }]
  }

  activate();

  ctrl.submit = function() {
    $log.debug('form submitted');
  }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trollr/133hhwzx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $eval method, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) to parse the `'myDynamicForm.' + formField.formFieldId + '.$error'` string to an expression.

> **$scope.$eval** Executes the expression on the current scope and returns the result. Any exceptions in the expression are propagated (uncaught). This is useful when evaluating Angular expressions

Please see working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/cbsdetLa/1/)

Remember to register the `ngMessages` module in your application config.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" data-ng-controller="DynamicFormController as vm">
      <form name="myDynamicForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="formField in formFields">
          <label for="{{formField.formFieldId}}">{{formField.label}}</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="{{formField.formFieldId}}" id="{{formField.formFieldId}}" ng-required="{{formField.isMandatory}}" type="text" ng-model="formField.value">
          <div ng-messages="vm.onValidateMessages(formField)">
            <label ng-message="required" class="label label-danger">{{formField.label}} required</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="vm.onSubmitForm()">Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('DynamicFormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var self = this;

  $scope.formFields = [{
    isMandatory: true,
    formFieldId: 'UniqueField1',
    value: null,
    label: 'Email'
   }, {
    isMandatory: false,
    formFieldId: 'UniqueField2',
    value: null,
    label: 'First Name'
  }];

  self.onSubmitForm = function() {
    if (!$scope.myDynamicForm.$valid) {
      console.error('form is invalid');
      return;
    }
  };

  self.onValidateMessages = function(formField) {
    return $scope.$eval('myDynamicForm.' + formField.formFieldId + '.$error');
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified trollr's answer, and its working.
I added the attr, `ng-show="userForm[uniqueField.form_field_id].$error.required"`

Here is the solution HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<code>{{userForm[uniqueField.form_field_id].$error}}</code>
  <form id="userForm" name="userForm" `enter code here`ng-submit="userForm.$valid && ctrl.submit()" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="uniqueField in ctrl.uniqueFields">
        <div>
            <label>{{uniqueField.form_field_label}}</label>
            <input required="{{uniqueField.isMandatory}}" name="{{uniqueField.form_field_id}}" ng-model="uniqueField.form_field_value" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="userForm[uniqueField.form_field_id].$error">
                <div class="error" ng-show="userForm[uniqueField.form_field_id].$error.required" ng-message="required">Please enter a {{uniqueField.form_field_label}}.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit
    </button>
</form>
</div>
```

And the Controller:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($log) {
    var ctrl = this;

    function activate() {
        ctrl.uniqueFields = [
      {
        form_field_label: 'Name',
        form_field_id: 'name',
        form_field_value: '',
        isMandatory: true
      }
    ]
    }

    activate();

  ctrl.submit = function() {
    $log.debug('form submitted');
  }
}
```

Or you can use ng-form instead of form tag.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q386jmnw/